# systemd timer running at unspecified time

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-timer

I am running `sync.timer` and `sync.service` unit files on `systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13)`. The service runs a simple curl script (`/bin/sync.sh`) and is scheduled to run nightly at some time between 1AM - 3AM EST via the timer.

These has been set up for the last couple days like the following:

```
# sync.service
[Unit]
Description=Run sync
Requires=another.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=1200
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sync.sh
User=auto
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

```
# sync.timer
[Unit]
Description=Run sync daily between 1am - 3am EST

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 01:00:00 America/New_York
Unit=sync.service
RandomizedDelaySec=2hr

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

When I initially created these unit files, it ran at **07:45:14 UTC (02:45 AM EST)** on the next day as expected. However, the service has been somehow running at 00:02:xx UTC since day 2 instead of the specified time frame (notice how timer's `LAST` is at **`06:42:14 UTC` (`01:42 AM EST`)** which is correct, but `journalctl` of the service unit says it ran at **`00:02:26 UTC`** for the latest run)

```
# systemctl list-timers
NEXT                        LEFT          LAST                        PASSED        UNIT                         ACTIVATES
...
n/a                         n/a           Tue 2021-11-16 06:42:14 UTC 17h ago       sync.timer       sync.service
```

```
# journalctl -u sync.service
-- Logs begin at Thu 2021-11-11 21:02:16 UTC, end at Wed 2021-11-17 00:06:30 UTC. --
Nov 13 07:45:14 host-16core systemd[1]: Starting sync 
...
Nov 16 00:02:26 host-16core systemd[1]: Starting sync
...
Nov 17 00:02:03 host-16core systemd[1]: Starting sync
```

```
# timer status
 sync.timer - Run sync daily between 1am - 3am EST
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sync.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Fri 2021-11-12 18:20:23 UTC; 4 days ago
    Trigger: n/a
    Triggers: ● sync.service

Nov 12 18:20:23 host-16core systemd[1]: Started Run sync daily between 1am - 3am EST.

# service status
● sync.service - Run sync
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sync.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2021-11-17 00:02:04 UTC; 15min ago
TriggeredBy: ● sync.timer
    Process: 440319 ExecStart=/bin/sync.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 440319 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 17 00:02:03 host-16core systemd[1]: Starting Run sync
```

I have couple questions:

1. Why does `ACTIVATE` and `LEFT` columns have `n/a` value when the timer still runs on schedule?
2. Why does sync service log's timestamp (00:02 AM UTC) doesn't match with timer's `LAST` column (06:42 AM UTC)?
3. Why does sync service runs at 2AM UTC repeatedly?

---

edit: Updated timer's config to the following but still seeing the same behaviour:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=
OnCalendar=*-*-* 06:00:00
Unit=sync.service
RandomizedDelaySec=7200
```

Comment: Maybe something else is running it at 00:02?

Comment: hmm let me check

Comment: I originally omitted what I thought was unrelated detail, but sync.service have a dependency on "another.service" and that seem to be restarted at midnight. Looking more into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. timer will have `n/a` tigger if the target service is still running. In this case `sync.service` had `RemainAfterExit=yes` setting so when it finished running it remained as `active (exited)`. Removing this setting will ensure that the service will exit in `inactive (dead)` state and allows the timer to restart it
2. Look at answer #3
3. We had a separate script that restarted `another.service` (dependency of `sync.service`) at midnight. This triggered `sync.service` to restart as well